# How to dynamically change value of query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm building an app with Express, Postgres as database and Sequelize as ORM.

I have two models, User and Post. Post belongs to User and User can have many Posts. Each post has a type, which can be 1, 2 or 3.

I want to access to each user's name and how many posts he has, divided by type.

The response should be something like this:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "typeOne": 1,
  "typeTwo": 3,
  "typeThree": 5
}
```

The code I have at the moment looks like this:

```
router.route('/:id').get(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    where: { id: req.params.id },
      include: {
        model: Post,
        where: { type: 1 }
      }
    });
  const typeTwo = await User.findOne({
    where: { id: req.params.id },
      include: {
        model: Post,
        where: { type: 2 }
      }
    });
  const typeThree = await User.findOne({
    where: { id: req.params.id },
      include: {
        model: Post,
        where: { type: 3 }
      }
    });

    res.send({
      name: user.first_name,
      typeOne: user.posts.length,
      typeTwo: typeTwo.posts.length,
      typeThree: typeThree.posts.length });
  })
```

I get the correct response but I think this code could be written better. It takes a lot of time to compile it. How can I get the total?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and `count`

```
User.findAll({
    where: { id: req.params.id },
    attributes: {
        include: ['name', 'posts.type', [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("posts.type")), "postsCount"]] 
    },
    include: [{
        model: Post, attributes: []
    }],
    group: ['model.type'] // also try, group: ['Post.type']
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try this, what happens when I need to access the posts, not just the count?

Comment: means? didnt get you

Comment: How do I access all the posts and their contents? Post has a type and a content.

Comment: In attributes you can mention all your fields whatever you need